# Reset filter value on primeNG table

Tags: primeng

According to the documentation from https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table the reset method should "Resets sort, filter and paginator state."
The problem is that reset table method is not deleting the filters from UI. (although filters field from table.ts is {} after reset)

Please see the [this](https://github-vmghz6.stackblitz.io/) where I reproduced it.
The code can be seen [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vmghz6?file=src/app/app.component.html)
Filter the Summary table (see example) by Failed field (or any other field).
Press reset. => The table values will be reset but the filter value will still be visible.

The example is with the basic table but it's also NOT working with dynamic cols.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
    {{col.header}}
    <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
    <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')">
  </th>
</tr>
```

Do you have any ideea on how I can clear the filters from the inputs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Fixed it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vmghz6-ytjegc?file=src/app/app.component.html)

For input fields just add

```
[value]="dt.filters[<field>] ? dt.filters[<field>].value : ''"
```

where `<field>` is the field send in the `(input)` method.

```
 (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value,<field>, 'contains')"
```

For example:

```
    <th>
      <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'date', 'contains')"
       [value]="dt.filters['date'] ? dt.filters['date'].value : ''">
    </th>
```

Comment: This helped me on the inputs.  Thanks.  How could this be done with p-dropdowns ?

Comment: @M Akin, please see my answer for how this can be done for p-dropdown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61919691/5764320

Answer (score 5):

What if you just add ngModel to your inputs like:

```
<input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="dt22" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'date', 'contains')">
```

in code you'll define:

```
  dt22:string = '';
```

and then onClick will be:

```
onClick() {
    this.dt22 = '';
    this.table.reset();
  }
```

I know that this will require additional code, but this will definitely work (a just tried on your stackblitz code)

Comment: Hi. I thought about this, but this is a solution for a small table with static columns. If the columns and filters are dynamically generated or if there are 20 columns in the table then there is no way I can bind the input to a variable declared in the `component.ts`. I need a generic solution that can be applied to large tables, some of them with dynamic columns.

Comment: If you need to make it dynamic - just use string[] instead of set of hardcoded variables.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on your question about the p-multiSelects... you can fix this by binding the `ngModel` property to checking the value of the data table's filter. You can use this same approach for the input fields as well.

For an input field:

```
<input pInputText placeholder='Search' 
                  type='text'
                  [ngModel]="dt.filters['foobar']? dt.filters['foobar'].value : ''" 
                  (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, 'foobar', 'contains')"
>
```

For a p-multiSelect dropdown:

```
<p-multiSelect appendTo="body" 
               [options]="[{label: 'Foo', value: 'Foo'}, {label: 'Bar', value: "Bar'}]" 
               [ngModel]="dt.filters['foobar']? dt.filters['foobar'].value: []" 
               (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, 'foobar', 'in')">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Finally, calling `Table.reset()` will completely reset all sorting, filtering and pagination.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
(onChange)="value = $event.value === 'Reset Value' ? '' : 
 $event.value;
datatable.filter(value, column.field, column.filterMatchMode); 
doFilter($event.value)"
```

Because `dt.filter()` with empty value will be meaning clear the filter.hope it works...

Answer (score -1):

In case you are using `p-calendar` as a filter input  and not using `ngmodel` :

```html
<p-calendar pInputText #pCalendar1 *ngSwitchCase="'createdDate'"
(onSelect)="dt.filter($event, 'createdDate', 'customDateFilter')" class="p-column-filter form-control pCalendar" [dateFormat]="pCalendarFormat"
    [selectOtherMonths]="true" yearRange="0000:3000" [yearNavigator]="true"
    [monthNavigator]="true" [readonlyInput]="true"
    [value]="dt.filters[col.field] ? datePipe.transform(dt.filters[col.field].value, dateFormat) : ''">
</p-calendar>
```

```js
@ViewChild('pCalendar1') calendar1: Calendar

clearFilter() {
    this.table.reset();
    if (this.calendar1 && this.calendar1.inputFieldValue) {
      this.calendar1.value = '';
      this.calendar1.inputFieldValue = '';
      this.calendar1.updateInputfield();

    }
}
```