# PrimeNG p-table: How to clear p-dropdown filter values when resetting table filters?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-table

I am using PrimeNG `p-table` with a header row that has both `input` and `p-dropdown` filters and need to clear the filter values of the `input` **and** `p-dropdown` when calling the `.reset()` method on the table.

As other's have pointed out (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51402834/5764320), you can use `[value]` on `input` elements, but there doesn't seem to be a way to clear any non-`input` filter values.

How can I reset the filters values for the `p-dropdown` (and other non-`input` filter types)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a simple, clean way that you can use `ng-template` to accomplish this.

1. Put your `<tr>` that has your filters into an `ng-template`
2. Add the `ng-template` to your HTML twice using `[ngTemplateOutlet]` and `*ngIf` and assign a value that gets toggled so that one template is used for `true` and the other for `false`.
3. Toggle the value assigned to the templates when you clear your filters.

This "clears" the filters since Angular completely adds and removes the HTML of the templates from the DOM when they are toggled, which means that any values that had previously been used won't exist anymore.

#### HTML

This assumes you are using `<p-table #dt ...>` so that `dt` can be passed with your button click.

*Note: leaving some of the `p-table` related parts and properties out to keep it clean.*

```html
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="FilterRow" *ngIf="showFilters"></ng-template>
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="FilterRow" *ngIf="!showFilters"></ng-template>
<!-- Whatever your 'tr' content is goes inside this template, this is an abbreviated example -->
<ng-template #FilterRow>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
            <button (click)="clearFilters(dt)">Reset</button>
        </th>
        <th>
            <p-dropdown (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'equals')"></p-dropdown>
        </th>
        <th>        
            <input pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field,'contains')"/>
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

#### TypeScript

```js
...
showFilters = true;
...

clearFilters(dt) {
    this.showFilters = !this.showFilters; // toggle the ng-templates
    dt.reset(); // reset the table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just manually clear them by referencing the in the ts component.

**Template**

```
<p-dropdown #myDropDown (onChange)="dt.filter($event.value, col.field, 'equals')">
</p-dropdown>
```

**TypeScript**

```
...
      @ViewChild("myTable", {static: false}) myTable: Table
      @ViewChild("myDropDown", {static: false}) myDropDown: Dropdown
      
      onResetTable() {
        this.myTable.clear()
        this.myDropDown.clear(null);
      }
...
```